# Diagonalize matrix with eigenvector of rank 1

Tags: matrices

Unsure how to diagonalize 
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
4 & -17 & 8\\
0 &1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}$
which has eigenvalues $\lambda=\{1,1,4\}$.

I am confused what to do with the eigenvalue for $\lambda =1$ $\Rightarrow\text{find eigenvector}\Rightarrow 
(A-1\cdot I)\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}\Rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
3&-17&8\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix}$
$\Rightarrow \mathbf{x} = \frac{1}{3}\left(x_{2} \begin{pmatrix} 17\\1 \\0 \end{pmatrix} + x_{3} \begin{pmatrix} -8\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}\right)$
Can I pick any values of $x_{2},x_{3}$?

Ultimately I should have the diagonalization

$
\begin{pmatrix} 4&-17&8\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} \frac{17}{3} &\frac{-8}{3} &1\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&4 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 1&\frac{-17}{3} &\frac{8}{3} \end{pmatrix} $

so how to choose eigenvectors to get this diagonalization?

Answer (score 1):

An eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is a non-trivial solution $\textbf{x}$ of the equation
$$(A - \lambda I)\textbf{x} = 0.$$
Denoting $\textbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T$, you find that
$$(A - \lambda I)\textbf{x} = 0 \Leftrightarrow 3x_1 - 17x_2 + 8x_3 = 0.$$
This implies that $$x_1 = \frac{17}{3}x_2 - \frac{8}{3}x_3.$$

Consequently, eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ are of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{17}{3}x_2 - \frac{8}{3}x_3\\
x_2\\x_3
\end{pmatrix} = x_2\begin{pmatrix}\frac{17}{3}\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} + x_3\begin{pmatrix}\frac{-8}{3}\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Setting $x_2 = 1, x_3$ and $x_2 = 0, x_3 = 1$ respectively, gives two linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$

The equation $3x_1 - 17x_2 + 8x_3 = 0$ determines a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which has dimension 2. The vectors above are linearly independent and therefore form a basis of the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$. The same will apply for the eigenvalue $4$.